# Cake php not able to set home page

Tags: cakephp

I am new on Cakephp. I am using latest version of cakephp. I have created an controller `"PostsController"` and want to make it home page. But when I have set it to home page from `routes.php` nothing happens. I am using subdomain like - `cakephp.example.com`. Here is my routes.php code

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index', 'home']);
```

Can anyone please help me why it is not working? Is there anything need to do in `htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

**Router:** (only once in your router class)

```
$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index']);
```

**src/Controllers/PostsController:**

```
public function index()
{
    // your code here
}
```

**src/Template/Posts/index.ctp**

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```